# Handle a size_t like an integer

Tags: c, types, casting

I have a function that It has to be in `size_t*` type. When all `size_t` types are declared as integers, all it works perfect. When I change the decleration to `size_t` it doesn't run with this fail `Aborted (core dumped)`. If i change all `size_t*` to `int` no problem happens.

That's the function:

```
size_t* sieve_of_eratosthenes(int limit)
{
    size_t *primes;
    unsigned long long int i,j;
    int z = 1;

    primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            for (j = i;i * j < limit; j++)
                primes[i * j] = 0;

    printf("\nPrime numbers in range 1 to 100 are: \n");

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            printf("%lld\n", i);

    return primes;
}
```

Comment: If it's a `size_t*` you need to use `sizeof(size_t)` in the `malloc()` calkl.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you need to use `size_t*` when the array only contains `0` and `1`?

Comment: ooh, sometimes when you are too many hours in front of a code you can't see anything.I didn't see it. Thank you

Comment: It's good to get into  the habit of writing eg primes = malloc( limit * sizeof *primes); that way you can change the type of primes and not need to change the malloc call.

Comment: yes sorry, i forgot to change the line printf("%lld\n", i), instead of printing I assign the value I to size_t *result  array and the return the result array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your lines

```
size_t *primes;
```

and

```
primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);
```

In the first you're stating that `primes` is a pointer to a `size_t`, and in the second you're allocating `limit` cells, each of size `int`. If in your implementation the sizes differ, this could lead to a problem.

You could change the second line to use `sizeof(size_t)` instead.

Comment: `std::vector` is C++, not C.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, didn't notice the tag. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than using `sizeof(size_t)`, it is preferable to use `primes = malloc(limit * sizeof *primes);`. Doing this habitually avoids errors in writing the wrong type when writing a `malloc` call, and it also automatically adjusts if the definition of the identifier changes.